# MSSQL - Table design for entities, customers and suppliers

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am working on designing a database for an ecommerce website. I am having second doubts so I decided to ask the community.

My thoughts are related to the following user flow: users can register on the platform. An user can be a customer that might register via social auth or via email + password. Also, an user can be a supplier that will be able to register via email + password. I was thinking to initially store the information from both types in a central table (`person`) and then, to normalize further in a `customer` and `supplier` table. But I'm having second thoughts so I decided to ask the community:

**PERSON TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE Person.Person (
    uid uniqueidentifier CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_UID] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    code int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    description nvarchar(100) NULL,
    firstName nvarchar(50) NULL,
    lastName nvarchar(50) NULL,
    email nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    password nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    mobileNumber1 varchar(15) NULL,
    mobileNumber2 varchar(15) NULL,
    birthDate date NULL,
    gender tinyint CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_Gender] DEFAULT 2 NULL, /* 0 - male; 1 - female; 2 - unknown */
    taxRegistrationNumber nvarchar(15) NULL,
    tradeRegistrationNumber nvarchar(15) NULL,
    websiteURL nvarchar (512) NULL,
    facebookURL nvarchar (512) NULL,
    instagramURL nvarchar (512) NULL,
    type tinyint CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_Type] DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, /* 0 - unknown; 1 - customer; 2 - supplier; 3 - contact person for supplier */
    created datetime CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_Created] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    updated datetime CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_Updated] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    inactive bit CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_Inactive] DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person_Code] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (code ASC)
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AK_Person_UID] ON [Person.Person] (UID ASC)
GO
```

**CUSTOMER TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE Person.Customer (
uid uniqueidentifier CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_UID] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
code int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
description nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
fPersonCode int NOT NULL,
fAddressCode int NULL,
fMainAddressCode int NULL,
created datetime CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_Created] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
updated datetime CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_Updated] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
inactive bit CONSTRAINT [DF_Customer_Inactive] DEFAULT 0,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer_Code] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (code ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Person] FOREIGN KEY (fPersonCode) REFERENCES [Person.Person] (code),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Customer_Address] FOREIGN KEY (fAddressCode) REFERENCES [Person.Address] (code)
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AK_Customer_UID] ON [Person.Customer] (uid ASC)
GO
```

**SUPPLIER TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE Person.Supplier (
uid uniqueidentifier CONSTRAINT [DF_Supplier_UID] DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
code int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
description nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
fPersonCode int NOT NULL,
fAddressCode int NULL,
fContactPersonCode int NULL,
fMainAddressCode int NULL,
created datetime CONSTRAINT [DF_Supplier_Created] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
updated datetime CONSTRAINT [DF_Supplier_Updated] DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
inactive bit CONSTRAINT [DF_Supplier_Inactive] DEFAULT 0,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Supplier_Code] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (code ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Supplier_Person] FOREIGN KEY (fPersonCode) REFERENCES [Person.Person] (code),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Supplier_Site] FOREIGN KEY (fAddressCode) REFERENCES [Person.Address] (code)
)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [AK_Supplier_UID] ON [Person.Supplier] (uid ASC);
GO
```

Could you please express your thoughts whether I should go for it or would you go with a different approach? Much appreciated the time and your input.

Comment: Sounds fine to me, especially if one day the same `Person` can be both a `Customer` and `Supplier`. Not sure why all your tables need both the `uid` and `code` columns though?

Comment: @J.D. - thanks for the input. No, a customer will never be a supplier or vice versa. Otherwise I'd have store everything in one table and differentiate via a field like `Type` where `1` would be customer and `2` supplier and both of these records linked to the same `personCode`. About `uid` and `code` it's for merging purpose (in case I'd need it in the future) as `uid` would provide unique values across servers/tables etc.

Comment: I'm very worried about seeing the password column defined as `nvarchar(50)`. Passwords should never be stored in clear text.

Comment: @AMtwo - will be encrypted :). It's just a draft but not the final design.

Comment: Gotcha. With an identity primary key you can still architect it to be globally unique, you just need to make sure whenever you insert into the table from an external source, you use the `OUTPUT` clause to get the newly generated values returned to that external source. But some might consider this more work to implement.